# Comparing years in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to compare data (in hour or day) of 2 or 3 years in a same chart with the same period (only date, do not care about the year). They need to be overlapped to each others. I wonder if Highcharts supports this ? Because there are so many cases to be concerned like leap day, time shift...

In the below example, I had tried to use two x-axises to display 2 series. But the display is not correct after the 29th Feb (the data of 29th-Feb 2016 will be compared with 1st-Mar 2015 which is unexpected)

```
xAxis: [{
                type: 'datetime',
                min: new Date('2016/02/22').getTime(),
                max: new Date('2016/03/05').getTime()

            }, {
                type: 'datetime',
                min: new Date('2015/02/22').getTime(),
                max: new Date('2015/03/06').getTime()
            }]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bernhard_kern/85s2fm5a/3/

Comment: If you want to account for something like leap year, you need to pre-process your data, and make sure each series has a (null) point for February 29th. There is no way for the chart to figure that out.  In general, you can either use multiple x axes, one each for each year, or you can normalize your data to all use the same date values, and differentiate them in the tooltip using the formatter. Each approach has its own pros and cons.

Comment: See my answer here for more info:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748588/can-i-sychronize-two-highcharts-series-with-different-years-leap-year