# Can I sychronize two highcharts series with different years (leap year)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, linechart, leap-year

The problem is best described in following **fiddle**:
https://jsfiddle.net/bernhard_kern/85s2fm5a/3/.
We use two series and two xAxis.

```
xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime',
        min: new Date('2016/02/22').getTime(),
        max: new Date('2016/03/05').getTime()

    }, {
        type: 'datetime',
        min: new Date('2015/02/22').getTime(),
        max: new Date('2015/03/06').getTime()
    }],
```

I want to compare yearly timseries, which have a **different amount of values** due to leap year (2016, 29 Feb.).

> Requirement:
>   **Display the equal dates below each other, even if there is a leap year.**

In the example you can see that *Mar 1 is displayed below Feb 29*. For the non leap year timeseries there should be a gap. Even if I add a null value on Mar 1, *I cannot stop the room time continuum*.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 6):

I would approach it this way:

1) use a single x axis, with a pointStart using the current year (or, whichever year is a leap year, to make sure you can account for the leap day. *It doesn't even matter what year is used here, as long as it is a leap year. You could use 1976 with no effect on the end result*)

2) at the date of the leap day, in the data series that does NOT have a leap day, insert a null value

3) use series name to denote the year in question, and in the tooltip (and/or anywhere else that you need to display the date), format the date to return without the year.

**Code example:**

```
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 1, 22),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      crosshairs: true,
      dateTimeLabelFormats : {
        day:"%b %e"
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
      name: '2015',
      data: [176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, null, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0],
    },{
      name:'2016',
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    }]
  });
```

**Fiddle:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/85s2fm5a/5/

Comment: Hi @jlbriggs, thanks for your answer. We first tried this approach, but then found the several x-Axis version and thought it to be easier to understand.  But I think this is easier to implement. We will think about that.

Comment: This is indeed the right approach. In contrast to the Highcharts example where they have chosen unix time t=0 (1970), which is not a leap year. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time .